# Confused about the default buffer size of stdout

Tags: c++, io, buffer, stdout

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {
       printf("1 ");
    }
    while(1);
}
```

Is `stdout` use `line buffered` in default? If so, we will not see ten `1` on the console when execute the code above. What confused me is:

On windows system with gcc: the `1` is printed immediately.

On ubuntu system with  gcc: the `1` is not printed.

I use `cout<<stdout->_bufsiz` to check the buffer size on windows, it is `0`, does it mean that the stdout on windows is `unbuffered` in default?

`cout<<stdout->_bufsiz` is not work on ubuntu, how can I get the buffer size of stdout ?

When I replace `while(1);` with `getchar();`,  `1` is printed immediately both on windows and ubuntu, why? `getchar();` flush the stdout buffer ?

Thanks.

Comment: The variable `stdout` have nothing to do with `std::cout`. The `stdout` variable is used by the old C functions like `printf`, while the C++ streams uses their own buffers. There is no way of getting the buffer size of the underlying [`basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) used by C++ streams.

Comment: I replace `cin` with `printf`, it is still the same problem. @JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 2):

The question is, which buffer do you mean?

1. the ostream buffer?
2. the buffer of the file stream under the STDOUT file descriptor?
3. the buffer beneath that in whatever device STDOUT happens to be built on?

If it's 1 I think you're doing the right thing.

If it's 2, then you're out of luck. see the documentation of setbuf() here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html as far as I know there is no getbuf equivalent. (can someone correct me here?)

If it's 3 then I think you're really out of luck.

Comment: I mean the stdout buffer when I call `printf`

Answer (score 0):

On linux you can do these to flush the buffer :

```
cout << "1 " << "\n";
```

or

```
cout << "1 " << flush;
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question

Comment: The first comment on the question answer it. Here I add a work around for Linux.

Comment: `cout<<"\n"` doesn't flush the buffer. `cout<<endl` does. And you didn't answer my qustion @AMDG